# prototypejs : holding functionality till ajax request result come

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

i am using new to prototype and using its ajax functionality but not able to set the values to return type
my code is

```
var captchaRequest = new Ajax.Request('http://www.example.com/captcha/validate.php', {
       parameters: "captcha_code="+captcha_code,
   onSuccess: function(result) {

    if(result.responseText == 'true') {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
                 alert('in ajax response');

       }
});
alert('after ajax')
```

what i want to do is execute some functionality after ajax call is complete and but my second alert which is 'after ajax' is getting executed before 'in ajax response'. 
I want to use code result from ajax response.
please help.

Thank you,
pankaj

Comment: I have solve this by setting "asynchronous" to true it's working fine now but I want to know what is a drawback of using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set it to async. Just call your function from within the onsuccess block.

```
  var captchaRequest = new Ajax.Request('http://www.example.com/captcha/validate.php', {
               parameters: "captcha_code="+captcha_code,
           onSuccess: function(result) {

        if(result.responseText == 'true') {
         **callMyFunction()**
         return true;
        } else {
         return false;
        }
                     alert('in ajax response');

           }
    });
    alert('after ajax')
```

Comment: Yeah, a much more thought out answer. You get a vote up from me.

Comment: actually this code is in one function and i can't write more functions in this block.

Comment: You're not, you're CALLING a function from this block.

Comment: but still it will not wait for function call it executes next line of code. it has been solved now, can you tell me what is a drawback of setting "asynchronous" to true

Comment: Synchronous means your entire page pauses while the ajax call is being made. Asynchronous meas is happen in the background and fire and event when complete, in this case "onSuccess".